What is this seal along the base of my kitchen cabinets called?
My kitchen cabinets have this clear plastic profile at the bottom edge of the toe kick. By what keywords can I find it in a store on the Internet?
I've seen discussion regarding their ugliness or usefulness, but none of them refer to it by anything but "those clear plastic things" (I like them, for what it's worth: they keep the worst of the spills out from under the cabinet, and they keep the toe kick trivially removable for cleaning (unlike what sealing with silicone would do).
(EU, if it's relevant for terminology)


Plinth seal capping, plinth profile, plinth edging... the issue I had with finding it seems to be that it's named with "plinth" not "toe-kick".

Interesting, we've always called it the "kicking board" in the UK, well, Notts at least.

Eh, yeah, as many Englishes as there are English-speaking count(r)ies, and some extra for random internet communities.
